# Traversal of LinkedStack and displaying the entire stack

Tags: java

Ok so im trying to Print out with toString() the following bottom|5|4|3|top.

```
public String toString(){
    String logString = "bottom|";
    LLNode<T> node;
    node = top;

    while (node != null){
        logString = logString + node.getInfo() + "|";
        node = node.getLink();
        return logString + "top";
    }
    return "Empty Stack";
}
```

it works with 0 elements in the stack, and with 1 element in the stack however my test case fails with the full 3 elements.

Im lost as to how to get the first two items in the linked list. `node = node.getLink();` moves you forward in a list, so its only showing the last item(top) in the stack which is 3 and then terminating the loop. How do I go backwards?

```
@Test  
public void test_toString_on_a_stack_with_multiple_elements() {
    stk1.push(5); stk1.push(4); stk1.push(3);
    Assert.assertEquals("bottom|5|4|3|top", stk1.toString());
}   

expected <bottom|5|4|3|top> actual <bottom|3|top>
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not `return` inside while loop, but after it.
Moreover `StringBuilder` would be quite useful.

```
public String toString(){
    LLNode<T> node = top;
    if (node == null)
        return "Empty Stack";
    StringBuilder toReturn = new StringBuilder("bottom|");
    while (node != null){
        toReturn.append(node.getInfo());
        toReturn.append("|");
        node = node.getLink();
    }
    toReturn.append("top");
    return toReturn.toString();
}
```

Comment: its always the silly errors that get me. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: No problem. We are here to help.

Answer (score 0):

> It works with 0 elements in the stack, and with 1 element in the stack however my test case fails with the full 3 elements.

The problem is in the `return` statement inside the while loop.

```
while (node != null){
    logString = logString + node.getInfo() + "|";
    node = node.getLink();
    return logString + "top"; // only once the while statement will be executed
}
```

That's why it works with 0 or 1 element in the Stack. You should rather put that return statement outside the while loop.